# Texture not Showing in Rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing, uv

I have a question for the rendered image.

No matter what I do like changing the mapping into UV Maps or something like that for the texture of a material (Using image as texture), the color won't change like what I wanted.

It can be shown using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (*Textured Solid*).

but with the Blender rendering, it won't show the color, just white.

If I'm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and then choosing the *OpenGL* render image, then the texture is shown (colorful).

[image: Using OpenGL render]
[image: Using Blender Render]

[Here is the file if you are interested](http://obj.dropbox.com/sh/pv4bxkwrvxs006j/AADgy1kvjt-V0faqn12FhMX-a?dl=0)

Comment: Lamp.001 is flooding the scene with white light, try setting it's energy down to 0.3 or something. Also, check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voOxjkdcz1w

Comment: Did you assign the materal? ( Edit mode , Select all , click on the material , Assign )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at it , and you did something strange with the material . I deleted the material first

[image]

then i added a new material with the + button

[image]

then i did the steps to add a texture :

-Image or movie
- Wrap mode : UV

I also turned on Ambient occlusion in the world properties

[image]

My guess is that it is a bug , Or you did something i did not see.

EDIT : also make sure you dont have extension changed unless you know what it does

[image]

keep it on repeat .

Comment: Thanks mate. That really helps solving my problem. I didn't think that I should just make a new material and add the Texture for it. What I did was adjusting the texture like the image, UV Mapping or something like that but that didn't help. Don't know why, maybe that was a bug like what you just said.

Comment: Glad it helped ^_^

Comment: can you help me with configuration of the armature so that the object can just rotate in rotate mode in 2D (not 3D). And how to rotate the table on the middle without making changes to the foot of the table.(with parent bone as free weight, it will distort all of the object as a whole not. thanks)

Comment: can you re word that please

Comment: Em.. i always get a bad deformation for one of the mesh I have right there (the operating table on the middle) after I am done with the armature and parenting. Am I doing it wrong? The one part of the mesh that I don't want to rotate is having the bad deformation. I haven't got the hang of weight or something like that. Have you got a good link or something like that? And could you tell me how to insert picture on the comment section so that I could tell you exactly what I mean ? I am not very good with wording :) Thank you very much.

Comment: are you using one bone?

Comment: No actually. I am using more than one bone. Can you show me how to insert the pics on the comment section ? THX

Comment: hmmmm make sure you are adding weights to every vertice , sometimes the whole armature might leave out verts